# ASP.NET Core MVC. Mulitple await calls in a single async method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await

I am trying to transform my app into async one. As i learned web apps heavily use threads so it is important to release any thread as soon as possible.

This method does security checks for `IdentityUser` and saves entity to database using Entity Framework Core.

```
public async Task<Guid> SaveTextFieldAsync(TextField entity)
{
    entity = await security.ConfigureEntityBeforeSaveAsync(entity); //some preparation work
    bool canDo = await security.CanOperateWithEntityAsync(CRUDType.Create, entity); //some security checks

    if (canDo)
    {
        context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
        await context.SaveChangesAsync(); //request to database to save context changes
    }

    return entity.Id;
}
```

There are three `await` calls in a single `async` method. Is it a normal workflow in ASP.NET Core application?

Comment: what makes you think otherwise? it is important that you understand `await` and `async` do not create threads.

Comment: @foozy - it is totally normal.

Comment: If there are 3 places where naturally asynchronous work happens, then yes, `await` will release the thread whilst that happens. Can you add your `ConfigureEntityBeforeSaveAsync` and `CanOperateWithEntityAsync` methods?

Comment: @Bizhan is such frequent roundtrip threads to threadpool not expensive operation?

Comment: @Johnathan Barclay both methods asks database for currently logged IdentityUser.

Comment: Then your code is absolutely fine. It won't necessarily use multiple threads; it just ensures threads aren't blocked whilst your I/O is being awaited.

Comment: there shouldn't be any noticeable difference but I can't say for sure without profiling and knowing the exact alternative. If the async code is a pure operation then there is no thread, otherwise there should be a Task.Delay somewhere and that is limited to hardware clock (approx 15ms in windows) and so the more delays you have the slower the code runs. But at least it doesn't "occupy" threads.

Comment: Remember that your method returns immediately with a Task. A non-async method plods through the code line by line and does not return until all steps are completed. The caller has your task and awaits until it signals all internal operation is completed. You can of course cancel tasks and perform other operations on them. Your code is exactly what I would expect of an async method